# Reading files above the webroot

Tags: php, cakephp

In php, I'm trying to read a file that is placed above the web root (e.g. `/home/[username]/games/`). I am trying to read a .swf and an .xml file. I have it working well on my local LAMP server, using this code:

```
@readfile("/home/[username]/games/hangman/example.xml");
```

But, testing it on an external server, it doesn't work. No php errors are in the log, but when I try `file_exists()`, it returns false. I have checked, and double checked, that the file exists at that path.

File permissions seem to be correct (they are the same as my local server), and the owner of the file is the correct user.

**Edit**

A bit of an update; I followed what @gnur had to say and set my basename in my `httpd.conf` in the virtual host setting as:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/:/home/[username]/games/"
```

I tried setting it do a different value before, and it was throwing an error:

```
open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/[username]/games/example.xml) is not within the allowed path
```

Now, I just get a `permission denied` error when trying to read the file. So I'm wondering if the file permissions, or the owner, isn't right.

These are my current permissions on the folder under the games directory:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 [username] [username] 4.0K Jun  1 10:13 hangman
```

And then the files underneath that directory (The ones that I'm actually trying to access):

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 [username] [username]  293 Jun  1 10:13 example.xml
-rwxrwxr-x 1 [username] [username] 204K Jun  1 10:13 hangman.swf
```

Comment: Try not to suppress the error, you're using `@` which hides the error.

Comment: The reason you do not have errors, is because you suppress them using `@`. Please remove it and tell us the exact error.

Comment: can you provide some examples of the cli showing proof of your double checking of the file existence? I find these problems tend to be solved by fresh sets of eyes.

Comment: @tradyblix @Wesley van Opdorp Wow, I feel like an idiot! I'm getting the error `failed to open stream: Permission denied`. Is that down to what @gnur has said? @devians I had a co-worker check the paths, and they were correct.

Comment: that is exactly what I said :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has something to do with the `open_basedir` value of php.ini, see http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but can I set this at runtime with `ini_set('open_basedir', '/path/to/set/');`? Or do I have to do this in the actual php.ini file?

Comment: As of php 5.3 it is possible to do this at runtime, otherwise you will have to use php.ini

Comment: I decided to add it to my virtual host, as it's only needed for one site. So I added `php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/[username]:/home/[username]/games`. The first one is the web root of the site, and the second one is where the files are located that I'm trying to read. I now get this warning: `open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/[username]/games/example.xml) is not within the allowed path` as well as the permission denied warning.